# When .filter when dismiss event is called, it throws an error and doesn't work. It says cannot read the property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

The link for the code is: https://gist.github.com/intern0t/f5930f19ca0f004876a605820d9530c1

What i am trying to do is when the dismiss button is pressed, it should filter out that list.
It highlights  {list.filter(isSearched(pattern)).map((listItem) => (
as the error but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `result` in `state` to what was `result.hits`. You would need to do something like:

```
onDismiss = (id) => {
    const filtered = this.state.result.hits.filter((item) => item.objectID !== id);

    this.setState({ result: {
        ...this.state.result,
        hits: filtered
    });
}
```